# Не создается директория allure-results

Tags: java, maven, testng, allure, report

Пытаясь добавить allure в проект обнаружилось, что не создается папка с отчетами. использую Maven + TestNg.

Вот мой pom.xml
Перепробовал различные варианты модификации, но ничего не помогло. Надеюсь на вас.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.simbirsoft</groupId>
<artifactId>tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tests_default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <suiteXmlFileName>tests_default</suiteXmlFileName>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>aut_default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <config.location.aut>configuration/aut_default.xml</config.location.aut>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>env_docker_selenoid</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.MAVEN_IN_DOCKER</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <config.location.env>configuration/env_docker_selenoid.xml</config.location.env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>env_local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <config.location.env>configuration/env_local.xml</config.location.env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>configuration/${suiteXmlFileName}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <config.location.env>${config.location.env}</config.location.env>
                    <config.location.aut>${config.location.aut}</config.location.aut>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Как вызываете Maven?